# how to end chapter* and start chapter

Tags: hyperref, chapters, thesis

In my thesis template, the dedication and acknowledgements are chapter*{} while other chapters are chapter{}. The problem comes using the hyperref-bookmarks. What happens is the table of contents, appear nested in the acknowledgement section.
The  list of figure nests in the table of contents, and the list of tables in list of figures.

Comment: What document class are you using? Also, are you only loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), or [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) as well? Or how do you add things like `\tableofcontents` to your bookmarks?

Comment: I am using \usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}. The bookmarks get generated automatically when i use the bookmarks=true. I have not done anything on my own.

Comment: You should make a short compileable example file just consisting of the chapter headings which demonstrates the described behaviour.

Comment: I am not completely sure what your problem is. But you might want to have a look at a recent question of mine tex.stackexchange.com/q/66642/16865 I think your problem is similar. In any case you should load the `bookmark` package which enables you to influence the behaviour of bookmarks, see ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bookmark.pdf

Comment: someone just answered that I should put \phantomsection along with  the starred chapters . It actually worked!. Please re-write that as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution ...

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\bookmarksetup{depth=-1}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Preface}{preface}
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Acknowledgments}{acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
Thanks to everybody.

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{toc}
\tableofcontents

\bookmarksetup{depth=0} %or a number >0

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\phantomsection` before `\pdfbookmark` is not needed, because the letter already sets an anchor.

Comment: your solution helped me get what i wanted. using \phantomsection was enough. Thanks

Comment: @Heiko Thanks for comment. Have now removed `\phantomsection` from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is the lake of the line
`\addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}` after your `\chapter*{entry}`.

- **file**: Refers to the file you want to add a line. In your case, `toc`, for `tableofcontents`
- **sec_unit**: Sectioning type. In your case a chapter.
- **entry**: The line you want to add. Say, the name of the chapter.

I'd illustrate its use with an example. Imagine your stared chapter is called *Introduction*. Thus, you should add a `chapter` line to the `tableofcontents`, called `toc`, then in your code use this,

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{First chapter}


\end{document}
```

Hope it would help!

Cheers

Comment: Add contents line added another entry into the table of contents.