# Chapters without the "chapter" text in content

Tags: sectioning, chapters

Is there any way to use chapters without the `Chapter 1` etc listings? I want only the chapter name to appear not the number.

Comment: Could you please make your question more precise? Do you want numbered chapters in the text and not numbered in the table of contents? If you don't want any number at all, just say `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried `\chapter*{here your chapter}`?

**Remember**: If you use it and want to build a `tableofcontents` for each sectioning a `addcontentsline` should be added. See [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68309/how-to-end-chapter-and-start-chapter/68311#68311)

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

If you are using one of the standard classes (`book`, `report`) you can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and say something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{10pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\chapter*{Test Unnumbered Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code above doesn't remove the numbers for entries in the ToC; to remove these numbers, add to the preamble

```
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\bfseries}{}{}
   {\hfill\contentspage}
```

Comment: I tried to use the ```titletoc``` package for a similar problem, but when I runned the spacing between the chapter names is lost in the table of contents. Is there any way to fix this?