# TeX capacity exceeded in Table of Contents due to macro

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, sectioning, errors, chapters

I'm working on a macro that when given `Hello` will make a chapter named hello, and number it like this: `1 - Hello`, with the `1 -` inside the margins. I also want it to automatically label the chapter by lower-casing the argument and remove all the spaces, creating a `\label{chap:hello}`.

So far, I've figured out that to remove the "Chapter" declaration, I must use `\chapter*{}`, and I have to append other commands to make sure the chapter is properly numbered and displayed in the TOC.

- [How to remove chapter numbering without removing it from tableofcontents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110840/how-to-remove-chapter-numbering-without-removing-it-from-tableofcontents)
- [Chapters without the “chapter” text in content [closed]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68418/chapters-without-the-chapter-text-in-content)
- [chapter headings without the word "chapter"](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=638)

What I have now is:

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]
{%
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\stepcounter{chapter}
}
```

In a MWE (Minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{An Example} \author{Nobody}
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\stepcounter{chapter}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Hello}
\end{document}
```

(The title is needed for some formatting issues.)

When I test this though, I get the error:

```
line 10: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] \tableofcontents
```

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere:

- [TeX capacity exceeded error](http://handyfloss.wordpress.com/2006/11/30/tex-capacity-exceeded-error/)
- [Error Latex TeX capacity exceeded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64893/error-latex-tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000)
- [TeX capacity exceeded error](http://handyfloss.net/2006.11/tex-capacity-exceeded-error/)

It seems to be a very non descriptive error.
Help?

One request: If you give me a macro that does the entire job, please explain how it works. (With documentation if it isn't too much trouble)

Comment: You can't redefine `\chapter` in terms of `\chapter`. Why not simply say `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a little hidden infinite loop. You are redefinying `\chapter`, which calls `\chapter*`. These are variants of the same command. Hence TeX builds a huge stack, ending with an overfull message.

Comment: Perfect, using `\newcommand{\chapterx}[1]{} worked great!

Answer (score 2):

You can't redefine `\chapter` in terms of itself. Use the internal version `\@schapter` which is called when `\chapter*` is issued. We have to take into account that `\tableofcontents` calls `\chapter*`, so an indirect call has to be made.

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{An Example} \author{Nobody}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar{\@schapter}{\new@chapter}}
\newcommand{\new@chapter}[1]{%
  \@schapter{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \stepcounter{chapter}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE produces an error: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

Comment: @NictraSavios Yes; now it's fixed.