# Infinite loop redefining \chapter with \let

Tags: table-of-contents, renewcommand

**Q:** Why does this cause an infinite loop? (Full code below.) Does `let` not do what I thought?

```latex
\let \oldchapter \chapter
\renewcommand \chapter [2] {\oldchapter{#2}}
```

Using *report* as the base class, I want some listoffigures-type lists (e.g. \listoftables, \listoftheorems) as numbered appendices; e.g. "**Appendix A: List of theorems**"
To do this, I have an environment, `TocLikeListInternal`, that temporarily redefines `\chapter`. (This seemed the most reliable and straightforward option to support various packages' listings.)

**Full context:**

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \desert__listof_fix:nn #1#2
{
    \let \oldchapter \chapter
    \renewcommand \addcontentsline [3] {}
    \bool_if:nTF {#1}  % want numbered?
        { \renewcommand \chapter [2] {\oldchapter{#2}}   }  % always number
        { \renewcommand \chapter [2] {\oldchapter*{#2}}  }  % never number
    \bool_if:nF {#2}   % want in TOC?
        { \renewcommand \addcontentsline [3] {} }
}

\ProvideDocumentEnvironment {TocLikeListInternal} { m m }
    { \desert__listof_fix:nn{#1}{#2} }
    {}

\NewDocumentCommand \ShowListOfTheorems { s t! m }
{
    \begin{TocLikeListInternal}{#1}{#2}
    \listoftheorems[#3]
    \end{TocLikeListInternal}
}
```

Comment: Probably something to do with robust command

Comment: Symptom looks somewhat like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148857/250119 but maybe not;  then in the general case you have to look at the internal implementation to modify it anyway

Comment: By the way you should write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means. -- in this case at least include the documentclass line

Comment: @WillieWong right, deleted